# Neuraxle's RandomSearch() successor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, automl, neuraxle

I updated Neuraxle to the latest version (3.4).

I noticed the whole `auto_ml.py` was redone. I checked the documentation but there is nothing about it. On git it seems method `RandomSearch()` was replaced a long time ago by `AutoML()` method. However the parameters are different.

Does somebody knows how can I channel Boston Housing example pipeline to automatic parameter search in latest Neuraxle version (3.4)?

---

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, FastICA
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

from neuraxle.hyperparams.distributions import RandInt, LogUniform, Boolean
from neuraxle.hyperparams.space import HyperparameterSpace
from neuraxle.metaopt.auto_ml import RandomSearch
from neuraxle.metaopt.random import KFoldCrossValidationWrapper
from neuraxle.pipeline import Pipeline
from neuraxle.steps.numpy import NumpyTranspose
from neuraxle.steps.sklearn import SKLearnWrapper
from neuraxle.union import AddFeatures, ModelStacking


def main():
    boston = load_boston()
    X, y = shuffle(boston.data, boston.target, random_state=13)
    X = X.astype(np.float32)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)

    # Note that the hyperparameter spaces are defined here during the pipeline definition, but it could be already set
    # within the classes ar their definition if using custom classes, or also it could be defined after declaring the
    # pipeline using a flat dict or a nested dict.

    p = Pipeline([
        AddFeatures([
            SKLearnWrapper(
                PCA(n_components=2),
                HyperparameterSpace({"n_components": RandInt(1, 3)})
            ),
            SKLearnWrapper(
                FastICA(n_components=2),
                HyperparameterSpace({"n_components": RandInt(1, 3)})
            ),
        ]),
        ModelStacking([
            SKLearnWrapper(
                GradientBoostingRegressor(),
                HyperparameterSpace({
                    "n_estimators": RandInt(50, 600), "max_depth": RandInt(1, 10),
                    "learning_rate": LogUniform(0.07, 0.7)
                })
            ),
            SKLearnWrapper(
                KMeans(),
                HyperparameterSpace({"n_clusters": RandInt(5, 10)})
            ),
        ],
            joiner=NumpyTranspose(),
            judge=SKLearnWrapper(
                Ridge(),
                HyperparameterSpace({"alpha": LogUniform(0.7, 1.4), "fit_intercept": Boolean()})
            ),
        )
    ])
    print("Meta-fitting on train:")
    p = p.meta_fit(X_train, y_train, metastep=RandomSearch(
        n_iter=10,
        higher_score_is_better=True,
        validation_technique=KFoldCrossValidationWrapper(scoring_function=r2_score, k_fold=10)
    ))
    # Here is an alternative way to do it, more "pipeliney":
    # p = RandomSearch(
    #     p,
    #     n_iter=15,
    #     higher_score_is_better=True,
    #     validation_technique=KFoldCrossValidation(scoring_function=r2_score, k_fold=3)
    # ).fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("")

    print("Transforming train and test:")
    y_train_predicted = p.predict(X_train)
    y_test_predicted = p.predict(X_test)

    print("")

    print("Evaluating transformed train:")
    score_transform = r2_score(y_train_predicted, y_train)
    print('R2 regression score:', score_transform)

    print("")

    print("Evaluating transformed test:")
    score_test = r2_score(y_test_predicted, y_test)
    print('R2 regression score:', score_test)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: changed layout of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem, this is a new example that isn't yet published on the documentation site:

- https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/12uzcNKU7n0EUyFzgitSt1wSaSvV4qJbs (go see the solution to the 2nd coding Kata from there)

Sample pipeline code from the link above:

```
from neuraxle.base import Identity
from neuraxle.steps.flow import TrainOnlyWrapper, ChooseOneStepOf
from neuraxle.steps.numpy import NumpyConcatenateInnerFeatures, NumpyShapePrinter, NumpyFlattenDatum
from neuraxle.union import FeatureUnion


pipeline = Pipeline([
    TrainOnlyWrapper(NumpyShapePrinter(custom_message="Input shape before feature union")),
    FeatureUnion([
        Pipeline([
            NumpyFFT(),
            NumpyAbs(),
            FeatureUnion([
                NumpyFlattenDatum(),  # Reshape from 3D to flat 2D: flattening data except on batch size
                FFTPeakBinWithValue()  # Extract 2D features from the 3D FFT bins
            ], joiner=NumpyConcatenateInnerFeatures())
        ]),
        NumpyMean(),
        NumpyMedian(),
        NumpyMin(),
        NumpyMax()
    ], joiner=NumpyConcatenateInnerFeatures()),
    # TODO, optional: Add some feature selection right here for the motivated ones:
    #      https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html
    # TODO, optional: Add normalization right here (if using other classifiers)
    #      https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html
    TrainOnlyWrapper(NumpyShapePrinter(custom_message="Shape after feature union, before classification")),
    # Shape: [batch_size, remade_features]
    ChooseOneStepOf([
        decision_tree_classifier,
        # extra_tree_classifier,  # TODO
        # ridge_classifier,  # TODO
        logistic_regression,
        # random_forest_classifier  # TODO
    ]),
    TrainOnlyWrapper(NumpyShapePrinter(custom_message="Shape at output after classification")),
    # Shape: [batch_size]
    Identity()
])
```

Then do AutoML:

```
from neuraxle.metaopt.auto_ml import AutoML, InMemoryHyperparamsRepository, validation_splitter, \
    RandomSearchHyperparameterSelectionStrategy
from neuraxle.metaopt.callbacks import ScoringCallback
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


auto_ml = AutoML(
    pipeline=pipeline,
    hyperparams_optimizer=RandomSearchHyperparameterSelectionStrategy(),
    validation_split_function=validation_splitter(test_size=0.20),
    scoring_callback=ScoringCallback(accuracy_score, higher_score_is_better=False),
    n_trials=7,
    epochs=1,
    hyperparams_repository=InMemoryHyperparamsRepository(cache_folder=cache_folder),
    refit_trial=True,
)
```

This example is also studied within the Clean Machine Learning training of Neuraxio:

- https://www.neuraxio.com/products/clean-machine-learning-training